# nginx auth_request is ignored

Tags: nginx

Why is my auth_request ignored completely?

nginx.conf

```
server {
        listen 80;
        error_page 403 = @error;

        location = /auth {
                return 403;
        }

        location /api {
                auth_request /auth;
                return 201;
        }

        location /test {
                return 200;
        }

        location @error {
                return 500;
        }
}
```

I tried with different builds, 1.8, 1.15.12, 1.16.0 but no luck - this one is just debug and http_auth_request

```
nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.16.0
built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-pcre=../pcre-8.42 --with-zlib=../zlib-1.2.11 --with-http_ssl_module --with-debug --with-http_auth_request_module
```

debug file:

> curl -v http://127.0.0.1:80/api

```
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 http request line: "GET /api HTTP/1.1"
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 http uri: "/api"
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 http args: ""
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 http exten: ""
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 posix_memalign: 0000000001157370:4096 @16
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 http process request header line
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 http header: "User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2"
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 http header: "Host: 127.0.0.1"
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 http header: "Accept: */*"
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 http header done
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 event timer del: 3: 45085285
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 generic phase: 0
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 rewrite phase: 1
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 test location: "/auth"
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 test location: "/api"
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 using configuration "/api"
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 http set discard body
2019/05/01 20:50:14 [debug] 16471#0: *1 HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: nginx/1.15.12
Date: Thu, 02 May 2019 00:50:14 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

> curl -v http://127.0.0.1:80/auth
>   This one properly fails with 403->500

```
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http request line: "GET /auth HTTP/1.1"
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http uri: "/auth"
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http args: ""
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http exten: ""
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 posix_memalign: 0000000001157370:4096 @16
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http process request header line
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http header: "User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2"
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http header: "Host: 127.0.0.1"
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http header: "Accept: */*"
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http header done
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 event timer del: 3: 45294398
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 generic phase: 0
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 rewrite phase: 1
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 test location: "/auth"
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 using configuration "=/auth"
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 rewrite phase: 3
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http finalize request: 403, "/auth?" a:1, c:1
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http special response: 403, "/auth?"
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 test location: "@error"
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 using location: @error "/auth?"
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 rewrite phase: 3
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http finalize request: 500, "/auth?" a:1, c:2
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http special response: 500, "/auth?"
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 http set discard body
2019/05/01 20:53:43 [debug] 16471#0: *3 HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx/1.15.12
Date: Thu, 02 May 2019 00:53:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: close
```

> curl -v http://127.0.0.1:80/test
>   This one works as expected

```
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 http request line: "GET /test HTTP/1.1"
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 http uri: "/test"
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 http args: ""
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 http exten: ""
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 posix_memalign: 0000000002179370:4096 @16
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 http process request header line
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 http header: "User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2"
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 http header: "Host: 127.0.0.1"
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 http header: "Accept: */*"
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 http header done
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 event timer del: 3: 44763130
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 generic phase: 0
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 rewrite phase: 1
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 test location: "/auth"
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 test location: "/test"
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 using configuration "/test"
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 rewrite phase: 3
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 http set discard body
2019/05/01 20:44:52 [debug] 15699#0: *7 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.15.12
Date: Thu, 02 May 2019 00:44:52 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

not sure if important but I am running on rhl 6.1 with kernel 2.6.32-754.10.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: Looking at the log output, I see that is for `GET /test HTTP/1.1`.  You have configured the location `/test` to only return a `202` response and it does not have any reference to `/auth` or `/api`.  I also see the result from the log is indeed a `202` response.  What is the debug log output for `GET /api HTTP/1.1` or `GET /auth HTTP/1.1`?

Comment: @GracefulRestart thank you for answering. i simplified the example and updated the question with the info you asked